# How to get data from c function to cocoa(objective c) function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, macos-carbon

I am using `CFMessagePortRef` for inter process communication. for receiving data , i have call back method

`CFDataRef didReceiveDataFromOtherProcess(CFMessagePortRef local,SInt32 msgid,CFDataRef data,void *info)`

Now i want to send received data to my main controller. i can create main controller object in `didReceiveDataFromOtherProcess` and send data to main controller, but i want to write generalize message passing module. i am not able to access instance variable in callback function, delegate will not work in this case, so i defined `-(void)saveObject:(id)object` method  and saving object of main controller in global variable.

```
messagePassing *object = [[messagePassing alloc]init];
[object saveObject:self]; //in main controller

//in messagePassing
-(void)saveObject:(id)object
{
globalObject = object;
}

CFDataRef didReceiveDataFromOtherProcess(CFMessagePortRef local,SInt32 msgid,CFDataRef data,void *info)
{
//....
[globalObject didReceivedData:(id)data]; // sending to main controller
}
```

but in this case; if i will open two connection it will change my global object.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `info` is for. Pass `self` as the `info` pointer when you set up the callback. Then dereference it in the callback so that you can communicate with the originating object.

Be careful about memory management. If `self` is deallocated before the callback, you'll crash when you deallocate it. Make sure to remove your callback registration in `dealloc` so this can't happen.